GDB stepi doesn't work upon execve system call
I am debugging a small 32-bit binary to which I want to pass a specific environment using the env command like so:
# gdb -args env -i ./tiny_easy 

Later in gdb I issue a catch syscall execve command so that env halts just before execve so I can continue debugging the original binary from its entry point. i.e. by single stepping with si.
The problem is this does not happen:
# gdb -args env -i ./tiny_easy
GNU gdb (GDB) 15.1
...
Reading symbols from env...
(No debugging symbols found in env)
(gdb) catch syscall execve
Catchpoint 1 (syscall 'execve' [59])
(gdb) r
Starting program: /usr/bin/env -i ./tiny_easy
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/usr/lib/libthread_db.so.1".

Catchpoint 1 (call to syscall execve), 0x00007ffff7e9382b in execve () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
(gdb) si
process 314196 is executing new program: /home/martician/tiny_easy

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x69742f2e in ?? ()
(gdb) 

It looks like gdb doesn't stop at the binary's entry point but rather continues execution until it encounters a SIGSEGV. This is not what I would expect since si should step a single instruction and this is not what happens if I use 32-bit gdb and 32-bit env on a 32-bit machine:
tiny_easy@pwnable:~$ gdb -args env -i ./tiny_easy      
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.11.1-0ubuntu1~16.5) 7.11.1
...
Reading symbols from env...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) catch syscall execve 
Catchpoint 1 (syscall 'execve' [59])
(gdb) r
Starting program: /usr/bin/env -i ./tiny_easy

Catchpoint 1 (call to syscall execve), 0x00007ffff7ad97f7 in execve () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:84
84  ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) si
process 384951 is executing new program: /home/tiny_easy/tiny_easy

Catchpoint 1 (returned from syscall execve), 0x08048054 in ?? ()
(gdb) x/5i $pc                    
=> 0x8048054:   pop    eax <------- this is the entry point
   0x8048055:   pop    edx
   0x8048056:   mov    edx,DWORD PTR [edx]
   0x8048058:   call   edx <------- the 64-bit gdb does not halt at 0x8048054 but it SIGSEGVs upon this call (the SIGSEGV is expected)
   0x804805a:   add    BYTE PTR [eax],al
(gdb) 

So the problem occurs on a 64-bit x86-64 machine with 64-bit versions of gdb and env while not on the respective 32-bit equivalents. What could be causing this behavior and is there a way to fix it? My best guess is that there is some gdb context I should manually change when doing the switch between the 64-bit env and the 32-bit binary but I can't find any sources online.

the answer to your question aside, why use env if you could just set environment a=b in your gdb session? (You can also use set exec-wrapper env 'a=b' if you really need to use env)

execve both completely replaces the code and changes the program counter, so this might confuse debuggers. Single-stepping works differently on different processor architectures, including 32-bit vs 64-bit x86, I don't know the details but it's not as easy as telling the processor to just run one instruction, especially with a system call because you can't single step inside the system call (not unless you're debugging at the machine or kernel level). Disabling ASLR (set disable-randomization on) may or may not help.

@MarcusMüller I am writing an exploit for the binary which involves modifying the environment, so I intend to run the binary through env that's why I am debugging env. Anyway your suggestion to debug the binary with setting the environment in gdb would work with the only drawback being that I would have to set up the environment twice in different fashion (via env or gdb for debugging and non-debugging respectively).
